# Why does quoting not protect filenames that start with "-" against mis-interpretation?

Tags: bash, quoting

This might be a ridiculous post, but let's say we have a file called `-|h4k3r|-`, why doesn't this quoting work?

```bsh
cat '-|h4k3r|-'
```

I thought single quotes remove meaning of all special characters?

However this one works

```bsh
cat -- -\|h4k3r\|-
```

This one too:

```bsh
cat "./-|h4k3r|-"
```

But I don't get why this doesn't work?

```bsh
cat "-|h4k3r|-"
```

I'm only trying to understand why quoting doesn't work as expected in this example.

Maybe Bash has a special meaning for `'-` or `"-` ??

Comment: `cat` doesn't even have any way to know that the quotes existed in the first place. Both`cat foo` and `cat "foo"` (and `cat 'foo'`, and `cat \f\o\o`) turn into `execve("/bin/cat", char[][]{"cat", "cat", "foo"}, ...)` -- what's handed off to the operating system when starting a program is not a single command line, but a list of individual arguments, each as its own NUL-terminated string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are **two** programs at work here.
One is the shell, the other is the `cat` program/executable/utility.

While the shell holds the single quotes as "a quoting" option, cat doesn't.

The shell gives no special meaning to an initial dash (`-`) (in arguments), cat does.

The shell just change the arguments to the executed program based in some rules:

```
$ echo '-|h4k3r|-'
-|h4k3r|-

$ echo "-|h4k3r|-"
-|h4k3r|-

$ echo -\|h4k3r\|-
-|h4k3r|-
```

The `echo` command receives the same argument `-|h4k3r|-` (after removing quotes) and prints the same result in all three cases above. The quoting of `|` removes its *special* meaning to the shell.

The `echo` command has few options and doesn't fully understand the initial dash (`-`) and there are no additional actions that it has to execute.

But `cat` does have many options, as explained in its `man cat` page. Options usually start with a `-` and **all** letters following the `-` should be processed by the command `cat` (not in all OSs). For example `cat -n file` would number each line from the file.

```
$ cat file
Line 1
Line 2

$ cat -n file
    1 Line 1
    2 Line 2
```

But if we end `options` with `--` and still add a `-n`, it will be interpreted as a file name by `cat`:

```
$ cat -- -n file
cat: -n: No such file or directory
Line 1
Line 2
```

As it is possible to write directly a filename (a path actually) by starting it with `./`, `../` or `/` (this directory, the directory above and the root directory).

Answer (score 19):

The reason is that while single quotes actually remove the meaning of special characters, this refers to [variable expansion, globbing and word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) - i.e. those characters that are special *to the shell* and that are interpreted by the shell *before the result is passed to the program* - and shell metacharacters (such as the `|`).

The `-` is not a "special character" in that sense. What makes it special is that it is a *de facto* standard way to indicate to a program that the string started by it is an "option" argument. In fact, many (if not most) programs in the Unix/Linux ecosystem rely on the external [`getopt()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt) function for that purpose<sup>1</sup>, which is part of the POSIX specification and provides a standardized way to handle command-line parameters, and the convention of interpreting parameters that start with `-` as "options" is embedded there.

So, the single quotes ensure that the `-|h4ker|-` is passed verbatim from the shell to the program (`cat` in your case), [but also removes the quotes in that process](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quote-Removal.html). Hence the program still thinks that since this parameter starts with a `-`, it should be treated as an "option" argument, not an operand (like a file name to process).

This is the reason why many programs (again, all that rely on `getopt()`) interpret the `--` token on the command line as a special "end-of-options" indicator, so that they can safely be applied to files that start with `-`.

Another possibility, which you already explored in your investigation, is to "protect" the filename by either stating it as an absolute filename (`'/path/to/file/-|h4ker|-'`) or prepend the current directory (`'./-|h4ker|-'`), because then, the argument will no longer start with the "ambiguous" `-`. *Note that quoting/escaping is still necessary in this example* because the `|` is a shell metacharacter.

A nice demonstration is trying to create and list a file named `-l`:

```
~$ touch '-l'
touch: Invalid option -- l
~$ touch -- '-l'
~$ ls '-l'

< ... the entire directory content in long list format ... >

~$ ls -- '-l'
-l
~$ ls -l -- '-l'
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Feb 24 17:16 -l
```

---

<sup>1</sup> For shell scripts, there is an equivalent [`getopts`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopts) builtin command